# How can I change video audio and subtitle track in Exo player in android

Tags: exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Hy sir this code only for audio selection but can we select video, audio and subtitles also?

https://imbt.ga/iNBFLV8rSQ

```java
public void setAudioTrack(int track) {
    System.out.println("setAudioTrack: "  + track);
    MappingTrackSelector.MappedTrackInfo mappedTrackInfo = Assertions.checkNotNull(trackSelector.getCurrentMappedTrackInfo());
    DefaultTrackSelector.Parameters parameters = trackSelector.getParameters();
    DefaultTrackSelector.ParametersBuilder builder = parameters.buildUpon();
    for (int rendererIndex = 0; rendererIndex < mappedTrackInfo.getRendererCount(); rendererIndex++) {
        int trackType = mappedTrackInfo.getRendererType(rendererIndex);
        if (trackType == C.TRACK_TYPE_AUDIO) {
            builder.clearSelectionOverrides(rendererIndex).setRendererDisabled(rendererIndex, false);
            int groupIndex = track -1;
            int [] tracks = {0}; 
            DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride override = new DefaultTrackSelector.SelectionOverride(groupIndex,tracks);
            builder.setSelectionOverride(rendererIndex, mappedTrackInfo.getTrackGroups(rendererIndex), override);
        }
    }
    trackSelector.setParameters(builder);
    curentAudioTrack = track;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have made a github repo with different feature such as changing the video track, you should take a look [here](https://github.com/yoobi/exoplayer-kotlin/tree/master/qualityselector)

Otherwise you should take a look at the demo in Exoplayer Github,
you can copy this [file](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/TrackSelectionDialog.java) which do exactly what you need and then look at the implementation in this [file](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/blob/release-v2/demos/main/src/main/java/com/google/android/exoplayer2/demo/PlayerActivity.java).

Comment: Do you have code in java ?